# Remove dom elements by matching href with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to remove some 'a tags' that have img's in them only if the a href matches exactly. This is the code that needs to be removed-

```
<a class="slideshow" href="?Action=thumbnail&Width=500&Height=500&algorithm=proportional" rel="lightbox[eventer]" onclick="myLightbox.start(this); return false;">
    <img src="?Action=thumbnail&Width=80&Height=80&algorithm=fill_proportional">
</a>
```

So if the href is equal to the one above, the 'a tag' and 'img' need to be removed from the dom.

======edit=======

I am using a proprietary CMS that spits out tags within `href` and `src` tags, I can't actually edit the code surrounding the url which makes it a bit pokey.

Comment: Removed old version of my code from your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use code like this that will work in all browsers:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), item;
var urlBase = '?Action=thumbnail&Width=500&Height=500&algorithm=proportional';
var urlFull = window.location.href + urlBase;
for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    item = links[i];
    if (item.href == urlFull || item.href == urlBase) {
        item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
    }
}
```

Note: the code traverses the list in reverse order so that when items are removed from the DOM and the live node list changes, it won't affect the rest of the traversal.

Because `item.href` will usually return a fully qualified URL and not exactly what was in the original source HTML, we test it against both a fully qualified match and against what we were expecting in the source HTML.

Comment: Why not `var links = document.links;` so you ony get links, not anchors. Isn't the test just the `href`? so `if (links[i].href == '   ')`

Comment: +1 for not using a nested for loop like I was planning on doing before I decided to withdraw. Also like the use of the indexOf method. Very clever!

Comment: @RobG - xxx.href will return a fully qualified URL so comparing equality to the relative URL will never work.  That's why I use `indexOf()`.  `document.links` would work too though it gets `<area>` tags too - I just chose a different way to get the links.

Comment: That actually removes all the links on the page that contain the href string, so even the links that have an image path before the string are removed.

Comment: @Nik - feel free to make minor modifications to the href comparison if you have more specific requirements.  The thing you need to understand is that `.href` always returns a fully qualified URL so if you don't want a certain path in the front of the URL, then you will have to revise the test to exclude the conditions you don't want it to match.

Comment: @Nik - I changed the code above to use `.getAttribute("href")` which will return exactly what is in the HTML of the page so that can be compared directly to your URL string.

Comment: @jfriend00—in IE 8 and lower, the href property and attribute both return the full URL, neither returns a relative URL. `getAttribute` is broken.

Comment: @RobG - Yes, it is fun trying to make things work with IE piece of crap.  I guess the OP can combine `window.location.href` with their URL fragment and compare that to `.href`.  Personally, I'd try to understand the real problem a little better if it were my code and do something more robust than trying to compare to a URL fragment.  Since we have incomplete info on the real problem, it's hard for us to know what better options to recommend.

Comment: Unfortunately the url fragment is all I have to work with, I didn't realize this doesn't work in ie7, I had a crack at combining as mentioned above but had no luck.

Comment: @Nik - I'm done making mods for you as we slowly understand more of the problem you're actually trying to solve.  If you want to show what code you've tried, explain what didn't work and ask for help with that, feel free to do so.  You will also have to post examples of URLs that have the fragment in it that you do not want to match so we can better see what should match and what should not match.

Comment: Sure, I will update the question to outline the issue and is/isn't working.

Comment: @Nik - you didn't show what you tried when combining my code with `window.location.href`.  All you did was copy my code into your question.  What did you try on your own given the information we've provided?  We start to wonder if you're just asking us to write your code for you rather than we give you information that you can use to write your own code.

Comment: Yep, I shoulda linked to the fiddle that I was playing with (it wasn't very close). Thanks for the code and I am learning js more and more through the discussions and different solutions that come up.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) and [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild)

```
var url = '?Action=thumbnail&Width=500&Height=500&algorithm=proportional',
    as = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="'+url+'"]'),
    i, node;

for(i=as.length;i--;){
    node = as[i];
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

[support for querySelectorAll](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryse)

Comment: Are people dropping support for IE7 now so it's cool to use `querySelectorAll()` with no fallback?  In projects where I don't already have an XP selector engine, I use Sizzle myself, but because I still want my pages to work in IE7, I don't use `querySelectorAll()` directly without a fallback mechanism.

Comment: @jfriend00 well, i was about to do the same thing as your answer, but i though I'd do something different since you already provided it. That's why I also posted the compatibility table to show what is supported.

Comment: @Joseph—the table is wrong, qSA is not supported in the IE 8 that one I have avaiable.

Comment: @RobG as what I have come across, it works in IE8 in strict mode and limited only to CSS2.1, so it's limited.

Comment: @Nik This is not cross-browser friendly without fallbacks as jfriend00 mentions. I suggest you use his answer instead.

Comment: @Joseph—yes, it works in some modes but not others. It doesn't work generally.

Answer (score 1):

I like Joseph's answer, but if you need to work with browsers that don't handle `querySelectorAll()` then you can use something like the following:

```js
var url = '?Action=thumbnail&Width=500&Height=500&algorithm=proportional',
    elems = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' ),
    i = 0;
for ( ; i < elems.length; i++ ) {
    if ( elems[i].href && elems[i].href.indexOf( url ) !== -1 ) {
        elems[i].parentNode.removeChild( elems[i] );
    }
}
```

Comment: `.href` will return a fully qualified URL so the comparison you're doing will never match.

Comment: heh. i'm a retard. you're right. i've updated my code so it will work.

Comment: If you follow the comments on my answer, `.indexOf()` doesn't do what the OP wants either.  You also have problems because `elems` is a live nodeList so it changes when you call `removeChild()` which messes up your iteration.

Comment: well, that's what I get for casually answering questions while working on other stuff. looks like you have it covered.